# How to make rotate photos when you change position iPhones in ios app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cordova

Who has any ideas how to implement this? My application is created using the cordova 4.0.0, js html css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can CSS3 Media queries work with Cordova?  If so, try the following:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, cordova can work whith css3 media queries) i will tring it now)) thank's alot))